# Why I Am getting null pointer exception in this following code?

Tags: kotlin

My CustomProgressDialog class :

```
**class CustomProgressDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context) {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout)
    }
}**
```

This line is written in HomeActivity.class

```
 **private lateinit var customProgressDialog: CustomProgressDialog**
```

And in onCreate
**

```
customProgressDialog = CustomProgressDialog(this@HomeActivity)
    customProgressDialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent)
    customProgressDialog.setCancelable(false)
```

**

This I write in serverCheckLogin()   
`**customProgressDialog.show()**`           // here is error

Can anyone please tell why is npe error coming?

Comment: customProgressDialog is in HomeActivity class

Comment: When is `serverCheckLogin()` executed? Is it possible it is called before the `onCreate()`?

Comment: No, i called serverCheckLogin() in onCreate